# How to hide from my friends notifications about me joining some Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I know that friends can see in the new feeds bar when I join Facebook groups. How to hide from my friends notifications about me joining some Facebook groups?

Answer (score 2):

Change the privacy setting of your *Activity Log* to *Only Me*. It will hide your activities from your friends.

When you join a *Close* or *Secret* group, your friends who have already joined that group will be notified to approve your joining.

Read more [What are the privacy settings for groups?](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465?helpref=about_content)

Comment: I did it already, but a friend told me that he receives these feeds. I guess that probably he receive these when I join public groups.